# Making John, john and JOHN mean the same variable in python lists?

Tags: python

My question is this.

How do I make it so users can not make a new user_name John if JOHN or john are already in use.

Can I make user_name.upper() = user_name.lower() or something like that.

These names are been iterated through a loop of current_users. I want the loop to detect current users and disallow the use of a name if it has already been used in its upper() or title() forms.

Edit: If possible could I get the most 'pythonic' way of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an example, like what is your i/p and your expected o/p. Giving just scenarios would be difficult to help.

Comment: current_users = ['joe']

for user_name in current_users:
    if user_name == user_name.lower():
        print('Already in use')
    else:
        print('Welcome new user')

Comment: Assuming `user`='Joe' or joe or JOE, you can just modify your if condition above to `if user_name.lower()==user.lower()`

Comment: Okay. So if I want to allow them to use capitalisation then I just leave out the lower()?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension if you do not need to loop through the current_users for anything else:

```
if user_name.lower() in [user.lower() for user in current_users]:
    # user_name already taken
```

This would be the same as doing:

```
lower_current_users = list()
for user in current_users:
    lower_current_users.append(user.lower())

if user_name.lower() in lower_current_users:
    # user_name already taken
```

As you can see, a list comprehension requires fewer lines of code and is very useful for this type of thing.

---

Alternatively, a normal for loop can be used if you need to check more than one thing:

```
for user in current_users:
    if user_name.lower() == user.lower():
        # user_name already taken
```

Comment: So how exactly does the list comprehension work. Just so you know I am new to Python.

Comment: It creates a list based on the for loop you put inside the brackets. Here, I loop through the current_users list and for each user, put the name as lowercase in the new list.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions If you want the docs.

Comment: Nice. Just read up on that. That clarifies things a lot for me ! Thank you for this !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda (a small anonymous little function) and make all your whole list lower case, and then compare that the the lower new_name.  If it's new, add it, if not, don't.

```
name_list = ["John", "Sam", "Joe"]
new_name = "jOhN"

if new_name.lower() in [x.lower() for x in name_list]:
    print("nope")
else:
    print("new name, add it!")
    name_list.append(new_name)

print (name_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   for username in current_user_names:
            if ip_username.lower() == username.lower():
                Flag = 1
                print ‘match found’
            else:
                Flag = 0
                current_user_names.append(username)
```

Or simply just while you add your usernames add them in lower case.

```
your_userlist.append(username.lower())
```

And you can simply use the IN keyword to check

```
if current_user.lower() IN your_userlist:
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use the code below

```
existing_users = ["John","tilak","RAMESH","SidDDu"]
while True:
    name = raw_input("Enter a name: ")

    for i in existing_users:
        if name.lower() == i.lower():
            print "Name Already exists!Please choose another"
        else:
            existing_users.append(name)
```

Comment: Hope this helps

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you !! I think the part I am confused about is the use of lower()